# Compare second letters in Array of string

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have an array of strings

```
var strs = arrayOf("flow","flower","flights")
```

How can I compare second letters in items? So, if second letter in every items are the same return true. I confused, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work :

```kotlin
 fun Array<String>.allHasSameSecondLetter(): Boolean {
    val letter = getOrNull(0)?.getOrNull(1)
    return all { it.getOrNull(1)?.equals(letter) ?: false }
 }
```

You can call it directly on your array

```kotlin
var strs = arrayOf("flow","flower","flights")
val res = strs.allHasSameSecondLetter()
// Should be true here
println(res)
```

Notice the use of `getOrNull` instead of `get` or `[]`. Using getOrNull we are avoiding error, allowing this function to work on any array of string.

##### To go further

You can customize the function by passing the index that you want to compare

```kotlin
fun Array<String>.allHasSameLetterAtIndex(index: Int): Boolean {
    val letter = getOrNull(0)?.getOrNull(index)
    return all { it.getOrNull(index)?.equals(letter) ?: false }
}
```

Using this function you can use it to compare the n letter instead of only the second.

```kotlin
strs.allHasSameLetterAtIndex(0) // comparing first letters
strs.allHasSameLetterAtIndex(1) // comparing second letters
strs.allHasSameLetterAtIndex(2) // comparing third letters
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val input = arrayOf("flow", "flower", "flights")

val result = input.map { it[1] }.distinct().size == 1

println(result)   // Output: true
```

Or as an extension method on Array<String>:

```
fun Array<String>.equalCharAtIndex(index: Int) = map { it[index] }.distinct().size == 1

val result = input.equalCharAtIndex(1))
```

If an empty input array should return 'true' too, then replace *== 1* with *<= 1*.

Comment: That will crash if any of the strings have less than 2 characters… `.getOrNull(…)` is uglier than `[…]`, but I think this is one of the times it's needed. (You'd also have to consider what happens if _all_ the strings have <2 characters.)

Comment: …As a developer, you always have to be asking yourself, “How could this fail? What situations haven't I thought of?” It can be tiring, and not easy — it's a different mind-set from when you're constructing code and thinking if how it _should_ work, which is why software testing is often a separate rôle — but it's always good exercise.